# Converting a column into floats except first few rows i.e selective conversion in a column

Tags: python, dataframe, openfoam

I m trying to do some data processing but I m getting the same error everytime.
My dataframe (con_tc) looks like this as follows:-

```
Index       u_p0       u_p1      u_p2.........u_p100
x            0          0          0            0
y            0          0          0            0
z            30         50         75          1000 
0.01        0.5        0.6       0.43          0.83
0.02        0.56       0.94      0.94          0.7
....
1000        0.4        0.5       0.45          0.56
```

When I run this line of code

`con_tc.index = con_tc.index.map(lambda w: float(w) if (w not in 'xyz') else w)`

which is trying to clean the index into float, I am getting the error as

`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float`

The aim behind this is to convert all the numeric values into floats except x,y and z.
In basic term

```
Index
  x
  y
  z
  0.01
  0.02
 ....
  1000
```

If anyone can help me out it will be really helpful.

Comment: can you explain why you want to convert Index to float? Shouldn't you leave that for panda to take care. Also, do you want to convert the data in the columns to float or the column itself to float?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this way

```
con_tc[ 'float_u_p_0' ] = con_tc.apply( lambda x: float(x.u_p0) if x.Index  not in ("xyz") else x.u_p0
```